# High resolution live streaming using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming, video-editing

I use OpenCV 3.1.0 to capture live videostream from ip camera *HikVision DS-2CD2432F-IW (rtsp, h264)* with resolution 2048x1536, rps 20. And I would like to buffer a few frames. There is my profiling code:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://login:psw@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Streaming/Channel/1')
frames = []
while cap.isOpened():
    cap.grab()
    img_success, img = cap.retrieve()

    if img_success:
        frames.append(img.copy())

    frame_i += 1
    if frame_i == 200:
        break
```

The problem lies in the calling of *frames.append(img.copy())*.

If this line is commented - all fine.

If no - sometimes(!) there is an unclear behaviour of the *cap* object. There is either frame's outlier shown at profiling results of [cap.grab()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpPW5.png), [cap.retrieve()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1JHF.png), or too long average time of *cap.retrieve()* execution.

The feature is that timing of *frames.append(img.copy())* is stable and negligible (1-5 ms). At the same time it seems that *img.copy()* somehow influences on entry state of *cap* object because of [*img* references to memory of the *cap*](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-retrieve).

It occurs only on high resolution and not always.

My hardware: 32GB RAM, Inter Core i7 x 12

Any ideas?

Comment: is your problem in frames.append(img.copy()) or in cap.retrieve()? The first probably comes from your file system if memory is swapped (you are buffering quite a lot of data) and the second thing might be the decoding speed of your hardware platform.

Comment: 200 of your images are 1.75 GB

Comment: Hi Micka. I updated my question according to your notes.

Comment: Anywhere I checked free memory and saw lack of it. I am verifying this hypothesis at this moment.